# Second console prompt fails in Java

Tags: java, sorting

This is a class assignment where I have to get the user to input three names, then sort them alphabetically in descending or ascending order based again on user input.
I've got the input of the names down and managed to find a way to sort them but my code fails when I ask the user to choose between ascending and descending (ie: my following if statements don't execute). I'm sure it's a simple explanation but I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code:

```
package javaapplication9;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication9 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = getInput("Enter the first name: ");
    String b = getInput("Enter the second name: ");
    String c = getInput("Enter the third name: ");
    String ascending = getInput("Enter [A] for Ascending and [D]"
            + "for Descending order.");

    // find first name alphabetically
    String min = "";
    if (a.compareTo(b) <= 0 && a.compareTo(c) <= 0)
    {
        min = a;
    }
    else if (b.compareTo(a) <= 0 && b.compareTo(c) <= 0)
    {
        min = b;
    }
    else if (c.compareTo(b) <= 0 && c.compareTo(a) <= 0)
    {
        min = c;
    }

    // find middle name alphabetically (and by descending order)
    String middle = "";
    if (a.compareTo(b)*a.compareTo(c) <= 0)
    {
        middle = a;
    }
    else if (b.compareTo(a)*b.compareTo(c) <= 0)
    {
        middle = b;
    }
    else if (c.compareTo(b)*c.compareTo(a) <= 0)
    {
        middle = c;
    }

    // find last name alphabetically
    String last = "";
    if (a.compareTo(b) >= 0 && a.compareTo(c) >= 0)
    {
        last = a;
    }
    else if (b.compareTo(a) >= 0 && b.compareTo(c) >= 0)
    {
        last = b;
    }
    else if (c.compareTo(b) >= 0 && c.compareTo(a) >= 0)
    {
        last = c;
    }

    // This is where I am having difficulty. This part of the program 
    // never executes when I run the file and I can't seem to figure
    // out why.
    if (ascending == "a")
    {
        System.out.println(min + " " + middle + " " + last);
    }
    if (ascending == "d")
    {
        System.out.println(last + " " + middle + " " + min);
    }

} // end main function

private static String getInput(String prompt)
{
    System.out.print(prompt);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    return sc.nextLine();
}
}
```

Comment: Compare string with equals(String compare). Also your prompt asks for capital a or d. Don't forget to compare against capital a or d.

Comment: Everybody else has given you the answers. Some additional comments: don't call your variable 'ascending' when it can be descending. Call it 'direction' instead. Also, you are creating a whole new Scanner object every time you input a line. Just create a single Scanner object and reuse it for all input.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Code is cleaned up and working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly compare strings in Java you need to use the `equals(String compare)` method of the `String` class.

Because you tell the user to enter uppercase letters, use the `equalsIgnoreCase` method instead:

```
if(ascending.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
    System.out.println(min + " " + mid + " " + last);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing strings, use `.equals()`, not `==`.

Use this:

`if (ascending.equals("a")){`

instead of:

`if (ascending == "a")`

Full Code:

```
if (ascending.equals("a"))
{
    System.out.println(min + " " + middle + " " + last);
}
if (ascending.equals("d"))
{
    System.out.println(last + " " + middle + " " + min);
}
```

Comment: You also might want to use `ascending.toLowerCase()`.